# Is this correct code for dynamic array allocation in C

Tags: c, memory, dynamic

```
void dynamicArray(int** num1, int** num2, char*** str, int size)
{
    int i = 0;

    *(num1) = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
    *(num2) = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * size);

    *(str) = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * size);

    for( i = 0; i < size; i++){
        *(*(str) + i) = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) *5);
    }

    return;
}
```

Did I successfully allocate memory correctly for my ***char in particular? I'm trying to create a 2-D array of "sentences". I'm having an issue in my main program and I think this may be the problem.

Comment: It is *rare* to need triple indirection, and when one does need it, they are generally quite proficient with pointers. I hesitate to say that is the case here.

Comment: @WhozCraig and he is casting the return value of `malloc()`

Comment: Thanks for reminding me why I like Java.

Comment: no it should be size of int, I want an "array" that holds that number of int's.

Comment: The syntax is right as far as I can tell. I think you are trying to do several unrelated tasks in one function. For example, you can create a single function that allocates the memory for an `int` array and just call it several times if you need more than one array. Also, what issue are you having?

Comment: Whatever num1 and num2 are supposed to be used for, they never get initialized with a valid number.

Comment: @Aniket I saw that, but in hindsight, the allocations actually appear correct. The for-loop, i'm not so sure about. Either way, the casts should not be there, as you've pointed out.

Comment: @selbie They are initialized by the parameters passed to the function.

Comment: @Aniket Does `malloc()` not return `void*` any more? Or does the compiler do the conversion automagically these days?

Comment: @ChuckFricano it's possible to write unreadable code in java too

Comment: @Code-Guru in staring a this, I have to say now, sans'casts, this actually looks correct for what I think he's trying to do. Lord knows why he's doing it, but it does, in fact, look accurate unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Other than code "ettiquete" problems, is anything mechnically wrong? The issue I'm having is with the string array. In another function, I assign each *strPtr a string. When I do so, it overwrites all the values  before it. i.e. *strPtr = "You" *strPtr + 1 = hi. NOW *strPtr + 0 well equal hi.

Comment: @Code-Guru malloc returns void*, but unlike C++, in C, void implicitly casts to any pointer type.

Comment: @Vlad can you give us a sample of how you're invoke this, and a *brief* sample of how you *use* what it returns? As I said, this actually looks right (a little odd, but right).

Comment: @everyone: the casts are for my own benefit and are not needed.

Comment: @Code-Guru C compilers have been doing the implicit casting from `void*` to whatever type for decades now

Comment: Also, in 10 to 15 min I will post the error as another question if I cannot figure it out. I was trying to see if what I have is correct first.

Comment: @Vlad If your intent is to allocate a couple of `int` arrays, saving their addresses into some out-params, and a ragged array of char pointers, saving the address of that in an out-param, then allocating each char pointer in the ragged array a fixed string of five chars, then you hit it home. That looks right. The code that frees this is going to be just as "involved", but as-written I *think* it does what you want.

Comment: @Aniket It's been quite a while since the last time I did just plain ol' C...

Comment: @Vlad [a simple snippet](http://ideone.com/NLWI8w) that uses temps to clear up any confusion, but as I said, your code looks right.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> The issue I'm having is with the string array. In another function, I assign each *strPtr a string. When I do so, it overwrites all the values before it. i.e. *strPtr = "You" *strPtr + 1 = hi. NOW *strPtr + 0 well equal hi.

Since this code looks fine, but you're explanation here looks funny, I think you're *using* the arrays wrong.

```
*strPtr[1] != *strPtr + 1 
*strPtr[1] == *(strPtr + 1) == strPtr[1][0]
```

You should be using one of the forms from the second line, not the first.